# Screen won't turn on after suspend - Dell Latitude 7490

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, dell, docking

I have this issue with my Dell Latitude 7490 laptop a few days after I got it from work. I use a USB-c docking station at work and it may be the source of the problem.

The symptoms are the following:

- if the laptop is put to sleep while connected to the docking station (with a second monitor connected), and the system resumes after I disconnect the docking station the screen remains blank. The only option is to hard reboot...
- in general, if I put the laptop to sleep closing the lid the same thing happens (rather randomly). If I put the laptop to sleep using the Power button and clicking suspend, the system resumes fine.

This issue is rather annoying, since I always put to sleep my older laptops by closing the lid. I feel that this might be related to the docking station, since I noticed the first point above rather recently.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue? How does Ubuntu keep track to see if the laptop is connected to the docking station or not?